# Is it okay to share cringeworthy e-mails with coworkers?

Tags: colleagues, ethics

It is Christmas time, and people are acting weird. My boss and a few colleagues are sending e-mails with jokes and Christmas quizzes and such. They send these to a lot of people, but only people they are in connection with.

Is it okay for me to forward this to colleagues/friends that don't work closely with any of these people, as in:

> Look at this, cringeworthy amirite?

and then we'll have a bit of a laugh behind their backs.

What they are doing isn't private or anything, but I wouldn't make fun of it to their face, so I am quite undecided.

Comment: What do you mean by "okay"?  Is it moral?  That's a matter of opinion.  Is it safe?  Probably not.

Comment: Simple rule in this regards, if your okay with your boss and their boss viewing the content, then go for it.

Comment: Is it okay?  No, I don't think so.  Does it happen? Sure, all the time.  But if you decide to be one of those people, for God's sake don't leave a paper trail.  By which I mean, don't *forward the original email from your account.*  Tell your friends about it verbally.  While you're out of the office having lunch somewhere.  After making sure no one else from the office is in the same restaurant.  Or, you know, just don't do it.

Comment: Forwarding corporate email is generally dangerous. Generally, whatever you write in an email at work, make sure nobody would crucify you for it if it was printed out and pinned to the black board. If you feel you cannot resist, copy and paste the content, send it via your private email account to the private email of the recipients.

Comment: just totally forget it.  in fact **never forward email, for any reason** is a good rule to live by.  absolutely forget your current plan of "making fun of people by forwarding email" !!!

Answer (score 11):

Email is never done behind anyone's back. It's stored for long periods of time, available to your company at least somewhere in the hierarchy, and quite possibly assigned to someone when you exit the company, including all past, present and future emails to that account. Your company likely has (and certainly should have) an email retention policy, and quite possibly someone who reviews your communications should an HR issue arise. It's possibly subject to subpoena, so if you should ever have legitimate means to take legal action against your company, that email may be handed to you during a deposition or within a trial, and you can then be compelled to read that email out loud in front of the person you're referencing. Unless you're willing to do that, don't send the email.

Always email like it will be printed in a newspaper. Because someday it might be, and you can't guess why.

Comment: This is very much dependent on the local jurisdiction of the OP.

Comment: Thanks @NoBackingDown, I tweaked the language to cushion for that.

Answer (score 7):

No.

It's usually best not to allow this kind of stuff to spread any further than is strictly necessary.

People with any degree of sense will start questioning your sanity if you start sending these emails again, even if you're doing it "ironically".

Comment: If you have to ask at all, then this is the correct answer, period.

Answer (score 4):

You should not share *others* cringe-worthy moments, it is highly unprofessional, even if you anonymize it. As others have pointed out email is traceable and normally archived at a corporate level.

However, if you wish to engage in such festivities you could share some of your own cringe-worthy moments. It shows humility and self-reflection as well as giving others a laugh.

I know of a workplace which has a 'wall of shame' board, with the rule that you should only post your own submissions. It is fun and a bonding experience as we all mess up sometimes and owning up to your less proud moments can be good for team cohesion.

Answer (score 3):

> What they are doing ins't private or anything, but I wouldn't make fun
>   of it to their face, so I am quite undecided.

If you feel you must do this behind their back, then you should avoid it altogether.

Chances are high that doing so would get back to them and you would be embarrassed.

Take the high road. Have your laughs at their expense, but keep them to yourself.